# SFTP issue with shell script

Tags: linux, shell, scripting, sftp

Need your assistance to find the issue in the following shell script.

SFTP is not happening, but still the file is getting moved to TMP2 directory.

Kindly assist.

Code :

```
    host=10.10.xx.xx
    user=xxx
    passwd='xxxx'
    cd /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP
    test=`find . -type f -name "*.csv" -mmin +5 | awk -F "/" '{print $NF}'`
    lftp<<EOF
    open sftp://$host
    user  $user $passwd
    cd /SMSGW/incoming
    lcd /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP
    mput `echo $test`
    EOF
    echo "$test Successfully Transferred" >> /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/SMSBulkRes/sftplog.txt
    for test in BCAST*
    do
       newname="Yes!28887:""$(echo "$test")"
       mv "$test" "$newname"
    done
    mv $newname /home/mquser/CIFM_STORE/CIBS_BULK/TMP2
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Your code suggests that you are using ftp protocol and not sftp

Comment: @VivekGupta : Thanks for your reply.  Can you please let me know what's the issue in the script apart from protocol discrepancy.

Comment: My bad, now your edited post clearly shows that you are using sftp. just check by  running sftp username@10.10.xx.xx <enter> give password when prompted

Comment: @VivekGupta Password is absolutely valid.  This script is not working when enabled in crontab, where as when i execute manually it works.  But file name is getting changed in the same directory.

Comment: @Saibulu : in any case your file will be moved as it does not depends on sftp result, its an independent code. 2nd : use return status to check proper execution of sftp code (use `$?`).

Comment: @AmitKumar : Thanks for the reply can you please let me where i need to use $? after sftp block?

Comment: @AmitKumar : one more observation is, if we trigger this script manually sftp works absolutely fine.  But if it is enabled in crontab it's not happening.

Comment: two things: your $test for the ftp command is based on the *.csv wildcard (with a modified time), whereas for the mv command it's based on BCAST* - so you _may_ end up with a discrepency.  Second, as Amit pointed out, you decide it's successfully transferred without checking either for existence on the server, or exit code from lftp command.

Comment: yes use that after sftp block or after statement where you doubt execution, if it returns `0` means successful else not.

     And which user and shell you are using in both cases (i means manual and crontab)

Comment: @GregHNZ : Thanks Greg for your reply.  Even though my mv command is based on BCAST i am looking out in $test only right?  Still we can expect discrepancy.  And on point 2 sftp is happening when i trigger this script manually problem is happening only when it is crontab.

Comment: @AmitKumar : it returned zero(Manual execution).  User and shell both are same. I mean the user which i logged in as well the shell script executor in crontab is same

Comment: Redirect `lftp` output to a log file and include the log into your question.

Comment: please tell us default shell for user and command you are using while executing manually and also crontab entry

Comment: It got resolved.  Thanks everyone for the help.